# Padding Menu By JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to design a menu that when I hover a link , the link pushed forward and when I move the mouse out of that , the link moves backward.

I know I can done that with .hover function.I don't want to use jQuery Events. I want to use just javascript events that they are embed in html tags.

here is my attempt:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function MIn()
  {
    jQuery(this).animate({paddingLeft:"20px"},500);
  }
  function MOut()
  {
    jQuery(this).animate({paddingLeft:"0px"},500);
  }             
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li onmouseover = "MIn()" onmouseout="MOut()" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li onmouseover = "MIn()" onmouseout="MOut()"><a href="#">Download</a></li>
    <li onmouseover = "MIn()" onmouseout="MOut()"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li onmouseover = "MIn()" onmouseout="MOut()"> <a href="#">Register</a></li>
    <li onmouseover = "MIn()" onmouseout="MOut()"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li onmouseover = "MIn()" onmouseout="MOut()"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldnt use jQuery(this) in javascript function wout jQuery selector. You have to send element like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function MIn(elm)
      {
        jQuery(elm).animate({paddingLeft:"20px"},500);
      }
      function MOut(elm)
      {
        jQuery(elm).animate({paddingLeft:"0px"},500);
      }             
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul>
        <li onmouseover = "MIn(this)" onmouseout="MOut(this)" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li onmouseover = "MIn(this)" onmouseout="MOut(this)"><a href="#">Download</a></li>
        <li onmouseover = "MIn(this)" onmouseout="MOut(this)"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li onmouseover = "MIn(this)" onmouseout="MOut(this)"> <a href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li onmouseover = "MIn(this)" onmouseout="MOut(this)"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li onmouseover = "MIn(this)" onmouseout="MOut(this)"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </body>
```

Comment: Nice thing , Can you explain more!!

Comment: @user1182970, [Gaby](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9098196/1149495) explain why this works and yours not. Also, why won't you use bindings?

Comment: Damn, beat me to it. :) Basically every event has a target that fired it. So you're passing the target as a parameter to the function. That way, the function knows which element to apply it to. I do have to say that it's better to remove anything related to behavior from your html. The best practice is to create the event listener in javascript (if you don't want to use a framework). This gives you a nice separation between your behavior and presentation layers.

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside your methods is not what you expect it, because you are not binding the calls to the element.. but instead are directly calling it in the window context.. `this === window` in your case..

You should do the binding with jQuery

```
$('li').hover(MIn, MOut);
```

and remove the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attributes..

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/FydWH/

Answer (score 0):

You need the event handers to be on the `A`-tag, not the `LI`. You also need to make your `A`-tags `display:block` or `display:inline-block` in order for them to use padding.

Comment: If you set the padding to the li de anchor move to the right, because his parent get padding. So this is the right way, you're way isn't...

Comment: It makes more semantic sense to animate the links, not their wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

You use jQuery, why not the event api?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').hover(function() {
    // onmouseover
    $(this).animate({'padding-left': '20px'}, 500);
  }, function() {
    // onmouseout
    $(this).animate({'padding-left': 0}, 500);
  });
});
```

This code work well, a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/HXpPF/2/

---

The [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function is to stop the animation if the cursor goes of the li.

Comment: I have mentioned that without .hover

Comment: @Stefan, `.hover()` is a shortcut for mouseenter and mouseleave, [the source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/git/jQuery.fn.hover/).

Answer (score 0):

If you now for some reason really don´t want to use event binding you could pass the referens to the current element as a parameter/argument this way;

**HTML**

```
<li onmouseover = "MIn(this)" onmouseout="MOut(this)" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

**Javascript**

```
function MIn(el) {
  jQuery(el).animate({paddingLeft: "20px"}, 500);
}
```